# Break text into sentences using bash

Tags: bash, sentence

A sentence is a one that ends with period (`.`), exclamation(`!`) or question (`?`). I tried

```
tr '\n' ' ' <  input | sed -e 's/[.] \s*/. \\n/g'
```

I see `\n` added in my file but the line does not really break there.

I am using bash 3.2 version on Mac OS X Mavericks.

Answer (score 0):

See if this works. ( '\012' is new line character that tr command understands, you are replacing it with a blank space and then finally using sed to "capture" either a full stop/dot ., an exclamation !, or a question mark ? character using ( and ) and that whatever character will become available to \1 and after that you want \n new line for sed. sed boundary character that I used in the following example is **#**.

```
tr '\012' ' ' < someInputFile.txt | sed "s#\([\.\?\!]\)#\1\n#g"
```

Comment: This did not work me. I did finally figure out a solution - thanks to google. I had to put in a hard enter in the middle of a sed: sed 's/[.?!] /*\
/g' input.txt > sentences.txt

Comment: did you use ' or " in sed.